# Can I check a checkbox in CodeCeption without a form?

Tags: php, codeception

I'm trying to write a test using CodeCeption for a page that looks like this:

[image]

My code for the test is the following:

```
// tests
public function tryToUnifyAgents(FunctionalTester $I)
{
    $I->amLoggedInAs($this->operator);
    $I->amOnRoute('agent_index');
    $firstAgent = $I->grabAgentFromDB(self::FIRST_AGENT_NAME);
    $I->seeElement('#agent_' . $firstAgent->getId());
    $I->checkOption('#agent_' . $firstAgent->getId());
    $secondAgent = $I->grabAgentFromDB(self::SECOND_AGENT_NAME);

    $I->seeElement('#agent_' . $secondAgent->getId());
}
```

I have all the needed objects in the database but when I run this test I get "The current node list is empty.".

I run the code with XDebug and noticed that the exception is raised because there's no form containing the checkbox. Is there some way to go around this?

Thanks,

Comment: Please share more details, like the markup involved

Comment: Also, why not simply add a form?

Comment: @NicoHaase well... actually that's what I did right after posting this :). I didn't really want to make such alteration only for testing purposes but, in order to get this going I did. Thanks!